# path error when running Pytest tests from cmd

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have this issue with Pytest where unit tests run fine from PyCharm but doesn't when I run through pipeline "python -m pytest".

Below is my project structure:

```
Common
   |_____configuration.py
   |
Services
   |
   |-----ServiceA
   |        |
   |        |___src
   |        |    |___utils
   |        |           |__ __init__.py
   |        |           |__   helper1.py
            |           |__   helper2.py  
   |        |___Test
   |              |___utils
   |                     |__  __init.py
   |                     |__    test1.py
   |                     
   |-----ServiceB
   |
   |
```

In helper1 I have code as

```
 from Common import configuration
```

Tests runs absolutely fine when I run through Pycharm because it resolves all path but when I run it through pipeline, I get below error when running through cmd,

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Common'`

Can anyone help how to resolve this issue. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **pytest >= 7.0.0** you can register extra path using Pytest's **[pythonpath](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.0.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath)** config option. The path value should be relative to the **[rootdir](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.0.x/reference/customize.html#rootdir)**. So it might be *Common* or *../Common* or even prefixed with more parent levels.

If you use *pyproject.toml*:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = ["Common"]
```

If you use *pytest.ini* instead:

```ini
[pytest]
pythonpath = Common
```

Answer (score 0):

Added path to the common in test **init**.py and resolved the issue

sys.path.append('..\..\Common')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).